# Calling a non-existent executable from a batch script: don't show message box

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch script that starts a series of executable programs using `start` e.g. `start example.exe`. If the program doesn't exist, I get the following message box:

[image]

When running from a batch script, is there a way to cause `start` to suppress this message box and instead write the error message to stdout or stderr? Failing that, is there an alternative way to start an .exe in a non-blocking way from a batch script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I hadn't initially considered before I posted this question is to check the file exists before calling `start`, as follows:

```
if exist example.exe (
    start example.exe
) else (
    echo Error: 'example.exe' does not exist 1>&2
)
```

Strictly speaking, not a direct answer to my question as I originally stated it, but nonetheless serves my purposes fine.

Comment: Seems a sensible approach. Personally I'd wrap your logic up into a function (eg. one called `start_no_err`) and then just call that instead of `start` when you want to suppress the error.

Comment: You might want to attempt to generalize the solution to handle where the file might not be in the current directory, but nevertheless exists (in one of the directories in the PATH).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin good point. In my use case I'm calling a local executable, but you're right to point out that if I were targeting an executable in PATH the script would report that it does not exist even though it could be called with `start`. However, accounting for this would make the script more complex. This question may be helpful in this regard: [How to test if an executable exists in the %PATH% from a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781772/how-to-test-if-an-executable-exists-in-the-path-from-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Why are you using redirectors `1>&2` ? That's it superfluous...